# Is Zeta function discrete-analytic?

Tags: zeta-functions, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let's define discrete-analytic functions as functions that are equal to their Newton series expansion:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x-a}k \Delta^k f(a)$$

My question is whether $\zeta(s,q)$ ($q$=const) is discrete-analytic against $s$?

That is whether its Newton series converges and is equal to the function itself.

For comparison, in the following graphic there are four functions:

- **red** is the function $\zeta(x,3)$
- **blue** is $\frac{\cos (\pi x)\psi_b^{(x+1)}(3)}{\Gamma(x+2)}$ where $\psi_b$ is the balanced polygamma
- **yellow** is $\frac{\cos (\pi x)\psi^{(x+1)}(3)}{\Gamma(x+2)}$ where $\psi$ is the polygamma as implemented in Mathematica
- **green** is the partial Newton expansion of the above functions taken at first 20 terms.

The three first functions and the Newton expansion, if it converges, have the same values at non-negative integer arguments.

**notation**
$\zeta(x,q)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function, [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function)

Balanced polygamma [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_polygamma_function)

[image]

Comment: When you write $\zeta(s,q)$, do you mean the Hurwitz zeta function, or some other function with similar notation?

Comment: @Mrc Plm, what is standard? Why you think that if there no poles the function and expansion coincide? Why do you think the expansion converges? If you know, can you please also answer this question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/90744/is-exponent-of-discrete-analytic-function-also-discrete-analytic

Comment: Note, that in this graphic you can see three meromorphic functions that have the same Newton series expansion, but they are not equal!

Comment: @Carnahan, yes.

Comment: Mrc Plm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series

Comment: Thank you. I should improve my google skills, all I was directed to was the newton binomial;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this is OK.
$$
\zeta(s,q) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+q)^s}
\tag{1}$$
Let's first consider just one term, $f(s) = 1/(n+q)^{s}$.  Then
$$
\Delta f(s) = f(s+1) - f(s) = \frac{1}{(n+q)^{s+1}} - \frac{1}{(n+q)^s}
=\left(\frac{1}{n+q}-1\right)\frac{1}{(n+q)^s}
$$
$$
\Delta^k f(s) = \left(\frac{1}{n+q}-1\right)^k\frac{1}{(n+q)^s}
$$
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{x-a}{k} \Delta^k f(a) &=
\frac{1}{(n+q)^a}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{x-a}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n+q}-1\right)^k
\cr &=\frac{1}{(n+q)^a}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+q}-1\right)^{x-a}
\cr &= \frac{1}{(n+q)^x}=f(x)
\end{align}$$
We applied the binomial theorem, which requires
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n+q}-1\right| < 1
$$
so this works for $q>1/2$.

**Thus**  The question is whether the convergence in (1) is good enough that we can interchange two sums and get our conclusion...

But in fact for $q \gt 1/2, a \gt 1, x \gt 1$ we can interchange the sums in
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+q)^a}\binom{x-a}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n+q}-1\right)^k
$$
because, for $k \gt x-a, n \gt 1$, all terms have the same sign.

Comment: By the way, what is for s < 0?

Comment: In this argument, $a>1$.  Required because (1) fails for $s \le 1$.